# E: Unable to locate package libssl-dev when trying to download 32bit OpenSSL on 64bit system

Tags: apt, openssl, multiarch

I'm trying to compile multiarch project the right (means reproducible) way, so I decided to install all libraries through `apt-get`. But ever since the system noticed what I'm doing, it became hostile. While many people claim that you can install 32bit OpenSSL through this command:

```
apt-get install libssl-dev:i386
```

I ended up with this result:

```
E: Unable to locate package libssl-dev
```

I did `apt-get update` and my OS version is `Debian GNU/Linux 8` (*Jessie*). Am I doing something wrong?

I tried to check what `i386` libraries are actually available:

```
XXXXX@debianvirtualbox:~$ aptitude search i386
p   debian-installer-8-netboot-i386    - Debian-installer network boot images for i386                                
v   debian-installer-netboot-i386      -                  
p   installation-guide-i386            - Debian installation guide for i386                                          
p   installation-guide-kfreebsd-i386   - Debian installation guide for kFreeBSD i386                                  
i   libc6-dev-i386                     - GNU C Library: 32-bit development libraries for AMD64                       
i A libc6-i386                         - GNU C Library: 32-bit shared libraries for AMD64                                                 
v   qemu-system-i386                   -
```

Comment: Can you install other i386 packages?

Comment: Only the basic std c++ libraries. I'll add `aptitude search i386` results to the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suspect that you don't have the i386 architecture enabled.

```
dpkg --add-architecture i386
apt-get update
apt-get install libssl-dev:i386
```

For more see the [Multiarch HOWTO](https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/HOWTO)

Comment: Ahh. Thanks. And can I trust this to deal with everything correctly, avoiding name conflicts? It would be really great if I could install other libraries (like `boost`) that way too.

Comment: You should be able to install all i386 packages alongside their amd64 versions.

Comment: @ThomasWeinbrenner, not all.. the package has to be built with multiarch support.  Not all packages have been updated for this, and not all can be.

Comment: I just ended up with linker errors saying it cannot find some libraries that I've just installed. Is there something else I should be doing?